# Prime factorization in a program for class

Tags: java, primes

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = 0;
    int i = 1;

    System.out.println("Enter a positive number");
    n = kboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("The Prime Factors of " + n + " are : ");
    value = 2;
    while (n > 1) {
        i = 1;
        if (n % i != 0){
           i = 1;
           i=i+1;
           if(n % i == 0){
               System.out.println(" "+ i);
           }
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("1 and " + n);
            break;
        }
    }

  }
}
```

This is my program and I started coding a month or so ago, but the program is only giving 1 and the number as an output rather than the prime factors.

Comment: Where are you reducing n once you found that n is divisible by i? Also you should start **i** from 2.

Answer (score 0):

The program always gives 1 as output because of this:

> ```
> i = 1;
> if (n % i != 0) {
>     // ...
> } else {
>     System.out.print("1 and " + n);
>     break;
> }
> ```

Since `i = 1`, `n % i != 0` is false, because any `n` module 1 will be 0.
So always the `else` block gets executed and you immediately break out of the `while` loop.

Even if you fix this, there are many other issues in this program:

- The condition `n > 1` is non-sense, as `n` never changes in this loop, so the condition is always `true`.
- Checking `% 1` is pointless, as every number is divided by 1. You should start checking from 2.

With minor improvements, the loop can be improved to find factors:

```
List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
        factors.add(i);
    }
}
```

But this is not nearly good enough.
This will find all factors, not only prime factors.
For example, for number 40, it will find `2, 4, 5, 8, 10`,
of which only 2 and 5 are primes.
One simple solution is to add another method called `isPrime` that checks if a number is prime.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the simple trick for you: 
Just set the num from user input.

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

            // Take out the 2s.
            while (num % 2 == 0)
            {
                result.Add(2);
                num /= 2;
            }

            // Take out other primes.
            int factor = 3;
            while (factor * factor <= num)
            {
                if (num % factor == 0)
                {
                    // This is a factor.
                    result.Add(factor);
                    num /= factor;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Go to the next odd number.
                    factor += 2;
                }
            }

            // If num is not 1, then whatever is left is prime.
            if (num > 1) result.Add(num);

            return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the **prime divisors**, you can try:

```
    int i = 2;
    while (n > 1) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            System.out.print(" " + i);
            while ( n % i == 0 ) {
                n /= i;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
```

If `n = 960` it prints `2 3 5`.

If `n = 11` it prints `11`.

How are you sure that you don't consider a number that is not prime?

- The second `while` loop divides the number as much as it can. So, the number won't be divided by 4, because if could be, it was already divided by 2 twice.

---

If you also want to get the exponent for those prime factors, you can initialize a variable with `0`, increment it for every division, then print it to standard output:

```
    int i = 2;
    while (n > 1) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            System.out.print(" " + i);
            int p = 0;
            while ( n % i == 0 ) {
                n /= i;
                p++;
            }
            System.out.print("^"+p);
        }
        i++;
    }
```

If `n = 98` it prints `2^1 7^2`.